# Change DisclosureGroup indicator image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to change the indicator image of the DisclosureGroup in SwiftUI. Ideally I would want a custom image. I have tried to achieve that using my own `ButtonStyle`

```
struct TestButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
        }
    }
}


struct DropDownMenu2 : View {
    
    var items: [String]
    @State var expand = false
    @State var selectedItem: String
    
    init(items: [String]) {
        self.items = items
        self.selectedItem = items[0]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            DisclosureGroup("\(selectedItem)", isExpanded: $expand) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedItem = item
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.expand.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.all)
            .buttonStyle(TestButtonStyle()).accentColor(.gray)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
}
```

Result so far:
[image]

I would like that `pencil` icon parallel to `Filter 1` text as is the case with standard `DisclosureGroup`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try using HStack ?

Comment: @Siempay yes, same result

Comment: @AbdullahSaeed Have you tried putting configuration.label inside of the HStack?

Comment: @Lalo is correct. The configuration.label needs to be inside of the `HStack`.

Comment: @Lalo you are right, putting the `configuration.label` itself inside the `HStack` solved the problem. Thanks a bunch. If you can move your comment into an answer I can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

If you can target iOS 16 you can exploit the [DisclosureGroupStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroupstyle) API. The following it's just a simple example to get what you need:

```
struct MyDisclosureStyle: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                configuration.label
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
            }
            .padding()
            .tint(.primary)
            .background(Color.green)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())

            if configuration.isExpanded {
                configuration.content
                    .padding(.leading, 32)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [String]
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some header Text")

            DisclosureGroup("\(items[selectedIndex])", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                VStack(spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                        Button {
                            selectedIndex = idx
                            withAnimation {
                                isExpanded = false
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text("\(items[idx])")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .disclosureGroupStyle(MyDisclosureStyle())
            .padding()
            .clipped()
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }

            Text("Some footer Text")

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: (0...9).map { "Filter\($0)"})
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]