# Dropdown menu button SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement such dropdown menu https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt4tI.jpg but could do it like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxPeY.jpg

The problem is that selected option doesn't have to repeated. Could you please help me how can I do dropdown menu like in design?

```
class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedOption: String = "За все время"
}

struct DropdDown: View {

let buttons = ["За все время", "За день", "За неделю"]
@ObservedObject var viewModel = MenuViewModel()

@State var expanded: Bool = false

var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Button {
                self.expanded.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text(viewModel.selectedOption)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            
            if expanded {
                
                ForEach(self.buttons, id: \.self) { buttonTitle in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    Button {
                        self.expanded.toggle()
                        viewModel.selectedOption = buttonTitle
                    } label: {
                        Text(buttonTitle)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        
    }
}


struct DropdDown_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DropdDown()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `List` and a `DisclosureGroup` to get it looking more like you want. But may have to create all the properties will a custom setup.

Comment: @loremipsum I tried to create like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519358/change-disclosuregroup-indicator-image-in-swiftui but values are also repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create computed property array in `DropdDown` View for store buttons without `selectedOption`

```
var availableButtons: [String] {
   return buttons.filter { $0 != viewModel.selectedOption }
}
```

And use in ForEach loop instead `buttons` array

```
ForEach(self.availableButtons, id: \.self) {}
```